# .htaccess rewrite rule with pagination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a mod-rewrite rule to handle pagination links on my site.

I'd like my url structure to be this: `http://www.mysite.com/classifieds/state/example?page=2`

I've tried the following: `^classifieds/city/(.*)?page=(.*) classifieds.php?state=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you want the end link to look like?

Comment: You have _state_ in your URL but not in your rewriterule pattern. Its _city_ instead.

Comment: Actually I need two URL one for state and second for city. I've tried the following: `^classifieds/state/(.*)?page=(.*) classifieds.php?state=$1&page=$2 [L]` but not working

Comment: I'd like my url structure to be this: `http://www.mysite.com/classifieds/state/example?page=2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need `QSA` flag to carry over existing query string.

Try this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^classifieds/state/([^/]+)/?$ classifieds.php?state=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^classifieds/city/([^/]+)/?$ classifieds.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot sir**, I was much worried because of this issue. I also do not want to change me URL structure. Thanks once again you save my time.